# Can you autorun with init.d files without a shell script script

Tags: bash, init.d

Is is possible to automatically run a program at startup using `init.d` (others may also work) without making a [init-script](https://github.com/fhd/init-script-template/blob/master/template). As an example maybe you could directly copy the executable into the `init.d` and then it automatically executes. Sorry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: You don't need to use the init-script in your link. The easiest place to automatically run programs is in your startup applications. What program are you trying to run automatically?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm trying to run some compiled C++

Comment: Does it need to run as root or user?

Comment: It needs to default to root but if it doesn't have the perms just use the user.

Comment: You can simply click Dash off the Luancher (first option) and type "Startup Applications" and add your C++ program (compiled name with directory prefix) as a startup application.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I may need to programmaticly add